# How to execute .desktop file by default

Tags: kde, dolphin

I use Dolphin with KDE and .desktop files just open with the text editor and I can't change it by default to execute, How do I make dolphin  execute instead?

Answer (score 0):

First, make the .desktop file an executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/file.desktop
```

Afterward, the application should launch when you double click the desktop file in Dolphin.

Comment: Made it executable via the GUI way, seems like I just didn't build the package (on arch but on askubuntu for some reason) Thank you.